# Custom TextOutputFormatter is not selected when Accept header is not exactly the supported media type, but only contains it

Tags: c#, csv, asp.net-core, formatter

I'm trying to add CSV support to the list endpoints in my REST API.

However I have the problem that my custom formatter only gets called when the Accept header is exactly `text/csv`. It does not work if I add a charset or a version (The API supports versioning).

So none of these work

```
text/csv; charset=utf-8
text/csv; v=1.0
text/csv; v=2.0
text/csv; charset=utf-8; v=1.0
text/csv; charset=utf-8; v=2.0
```

However the users of the API might send a charset and a version so this must be supported.

I already tried:

- Inserting the formatter at the first place. This results in it getting called all the time although my default should be json.
- Adding complete headers with charset and version to the `SupportedMediaTypes`. This does not make any difference at all.
- Adding `text/csv; charset=utf-8; v=2.0` and so on to the `[Produces]` attribute on the controller method. This works, but I simply do not know all possible combinations at compile time so this is impossible.

This is my class

```
public class CsvOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public CsvOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv"));

        // I tried to add these explicitly, but it does not change anything.
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv; charset=utf-8"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv; charset=utf-8; v=1.0"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv; charset=utf-8; v=2.0"));

        // UTF-8 is default, but all are supported if requested.
        foreach (var encodingInfo in Encoding.GetEncodings())
        {
            var encoding = encodingInfo.GetEncoding();
            if (encoding == Encoding.UTF8)
                SupportedEncodings.Insert(0, encoding);
            else
                SupportedEncodings.Add(encoding);
        }
    }

    public override IReadOnlyList<string> GetSupportedContentTypes(string contentType, System.Type objectType)
    {
        // This method only gets called during startup with either "application/hal+json" or "text/csv".
        // On my Controller method I have the attribute [Produces("application/hal+json", "text/csv")]
        return base.GetSupportedContentTypes(contentType, objectType);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(System.Type type)
    {
        // This method only gets called if the Accept header is exactly "text/csv".
        return typeof(Resource).IsAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        // This method only gets called if the Accept header is exactly "text/csv" if the formatter is at the end of the list.
        if (context.ContentType != "text/csv")
            return false;

        var resource = context.Object as Resource;
        if (resource == null)
            return false;

        if (resource.Embedded == null)
            return false;

        if (!resource.Embedded.ContainsKey(Common.Constants.ListItems))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        // This method only gets called if the Accept header is exactly "text/csv" if the formatter is at the end of the list.
        write the csv...
    }
}
```

This is how it is registered in my `Startup` class

```
services
    .AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new CsvOutputFormatter());
        // Does not matter if it is true or false, the result is the same.
        options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
    })
```

From the logs it looks as if ASP does only think the formatter is fine if the Accept header is exactly `text/csv`

```
[09:08:40 DBG] List of registered output formatters, in the following order: ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StringOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StreamOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter", "RESTworld.AspNetCore.Formatter.CsvOutputFormatter"]
[09:08:40 DBG] Attempting to select an output formatter based on Accept header '["text/csv"]' and explicitly specified content types '["application/hal+json", "text/csv"]'. The content types in the accept header must be a subset of the explicitly set content types.
[09:08:40 DBG] Selected output formatter 'RESTworld.AspNetCore.Formatter.CsvOutputFormatter' and content type 'text/csv' to write the response.
```

If it is `text/csv; charset=utf-8` it does not select my formatter, but the default JSON fromatter

```
[09:10:13 DBG] List of registered output formatters, in the following order: ["Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.HttpNoContentOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StringOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.StreamOutputFormatter", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter", "RESTworld.AspNetCore.Formatter.CsvOutputFormatter"]
[09:10:13 DBG] Attempting to select an output formatter based on Accept header '["text/csv; charset=utf-8"]' and explicitly specified content types '["application/hal+json", "text/csv"]'. The content types in the accept header must be a subset of the explicitly set content types.
[09:10:13 DBG] Could not find an output formatter based on content negotiation. Accepted types were (["text/csv; charset=utf-8"])
[09:10:13 DBG] Attempting to select the first output formatter in the output formatters list which supports a content type from the explicitly specified content types '["application/hal+json", "text/csv"]'.
[09:10:13 DBG] Selected output formatter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter' and content type 'application/hal+json' to write the response.
```

Comment: Do you want to receive many types at the same time, and then judge the types to give different Accept headers?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify supported charsets in the media type.

```
public class CsvOutputFormatter : TextOutputFormatter
{
    public CsvOutputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv; charset=utf-8"));
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/csv; charset=us-ascii"));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(new UTF8Encoding(false)); // Write UTF-8 w/o BOM
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.ASCII);
    }

    protected override bool CanWriteType(Type type) => typeof(IEnumerable<MyRecordType>).IsAssignableFrom(type);

    public override async Task WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
    {
        // Write CSV
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up inheriting `ProducesAttribute` and override it with a more relaxed version of the `OnResultExecuting` method. Instead of checking for an exact match, it will only check for contains.

That way the `OutputFormatter` only needs to specify the type as `"text/csv"` and does not care about anything else in the accept header, like charset or version information.

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
{
    base.OnResultExecuting(context);

    if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult &&
        context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Accept", out var accept) &&
        objectResult.ContentTypes.Any(c => accept.Any(a => a.Contains(c))))
    {
        objectResult.ContentTypes.Clear();
        objectResult.ContentTypes.Add(accept);
    }
}
```

The complete code is available here https://github.com/wertzui/RESTworld/blob/main/src/RESTworld/RESTworld.AspNetCore/Filters/ProducesWithContentNegotiationAttribute.cs